# Faster reading from blob storage via spark

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark

I currently have a spark cluster set up with 4 worker nodes and 2 head nodes. I have a 1.5 GB CSV file in blob storage that I can access from one of the head nodes. I find that it takes quite a while to load this data and cache it using PySpark. Is there a way to load the data faster?

One thought I had was loading the data, then partitioning the data into k (number of nodes) different segments and saving them back to blob as parquet files. This way,  I can load in different parts of the data set in parallel then union... However, I am unsure if all the data is just loaded on the head node, then when computation occurs, it distributes to the other machines. If the latter is true, then the partitioning would be useless.

Help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you will want to have smaller file sizes on blob storage so that way you can transfer data between blob storage to compute in parallel so you have faster transfer rates. A good rule of thumb is to have a file size between 64MB - 256MB; a good reference is Vida Ha's [Data Storage Tips for Optimal Spark Performance](http://www.slideshare.net/SparkSummit/data-storage-tips-for-optimal-spark-performancevida-ha-databricks).

Your call out for reading the file and then saving it back to Parquet (with default snappy codec compression) is a good idea.  Parquet is natively used by Spark and is often faster to query against. The only tweak would be to partition more by the file size vs. # of worker nodes.   The data is loaded onto the worker nodes but partitioning is helpful because more tasks are created to read more files.

Comment: Ah, I see. So with your advice, my strategy is to take the csv file and convert to dataframe so  that I can save to parquet files. By default, spark partitions the parquet files into 128 MB files. Then I can have a swifter data load for my subsequent loads from blob. Does this sound reasonable? BTW, thanks for the prompt response.

Comment: Yes it does!  You can start with the default partitioning just as you noted and then adjust as appropriate (a lot of the time, I just stick with defaults).   Best of luck and thanks!